# The solution of $y' = y^2 + \cos x, y(0)=a$ blows up in finite time for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

We are given the ODE $y'=y^2+\cos x$, $y(0)=a$. I need to show that the solution blows up in finite time (in both directions), no matter what $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is. Now, if $a \geq 1$, then comparing with the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ which satisfies $f(0)=1 \leq a$, $f'(x) = f(x)^2$ we get that $y$  blows up in finite time from the right since $f$ blows up at $1$ (and $\cos x > 0$ if $x \in [0,1]$). 
 Now, if $a \geq 0$, then by comparing with $\sin x$ which has a derivative $\cos x$ and gets value $0$ at $0$, we get that $y(\pi/2) \geq 1$ and we can continue like in the firs case. I am not sure how to proceed now. How do you solve this problem?

Comment: *Hint*: Integrate over interval of length $2\pi$, and argue $\inf\{\int_I z(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\mid \lvert I\rvert=2\pi, z'(x)=z(x)^2+\cos x\}=c>0$.

Comment: This is an Riccati ODE. Using $y=-u'/u$ it is equivalent to $u''(x)+\cos(x) u(x)=0$, $u(0)=a$, $u'(0)=-1$, which is a Hill equation. You could try the solution theory of this class of ODE. In the end, you need to show that $u$ has positive and negative roots, as these will be the poles of $y$.